# Conditional subsetting of data frame keeping previous row

Tags: r, subset

My data frame looks like this

```
       Model           w0        p0          w1          p1       w2      p.value

1   Null_model 3.950000e-05 0.7366921 0.988374029 0.000000e+00 1.296464 
2     alt_test 1.366006e-02 0.4673263 0.139606503 3.049244e-01 1.146653 
3     alt_ref  2.000000e-07 0.4673263 0.000846849 3.049244e-01 1.635038  5.550000e-15 

8   Null_model 2.790000e-05 0.7240479 0.987016439 0.000000e+00 1.263556  
9     alt_test 7.550000e-09 0.7231176 0.991768899 1.060000e-13 1.369259   
10     alt_ref 2.770000e-05 0.7231176 0.995373167 1.060000e-13 1.192839  3.073496e-01

            ...      ...          ...         ...          ...       ...        ...
```

What I want is to subset my `data.frame` in a way that keeps every case where  `p.value < 0.05` but it also keeps the previous rows to these cases.

So ideally my output will be something like this

```
      Model       w0          w1       w2
2   alt_test  1.4e-0.2 0.139606503 1.146653
3   alt_ref   2.00e-07 0.000846849 1.635038
```

I've tried the following but it doesn't work quite right:

> subset(v, p.value < 0.05, select = c(Model,w0,w1,w2))

the output doesn't have the alt_test row.

I have also tried

> with(v, ifelse(p.value < 0.05, paste(dplyr::lag(c(w0,w1,w2),1)), ""))

and the output in this case looks like

```
  [1] NA            NA            NA            NA            "0.013660056" NA            NA            NA            NA            ""           
 [11] NA            NA            NA            NA            ""            NA            NA            NA            NA            ""           
 [21] NA            NA            NA            NA            ""            NA            NA            NA            NA            ""           
 [31] NA            NA            NA            NA            ""            NA            NA            NA            NA            ""           
 [41] NA            NA            NA            NA            ""            NA            NA            NA            NA            ""           
 [51] NA            NA            NA            NA            "1.34e-11"    NA            NA            NA            NA            ""    ...
```

I also tried

> subset(v, p.value < 0.05, select = c(w0, w1,w2, w0-1, w1-1, w2-1))

but this gives the previous column, so I was wondering if something similar can give previous rows instead?

Thank you

Comment: Try `w = which(with(DF, my_condition)); DF[rep(w, each=2)-1:0, my_cols]`

Comment: @Rafael I don't see why the data.table tag should be added here.

Comment: @Frank, it is not strictly necessary, but it helps getting attention from people that uses `data.table`, which is quite handy for data manipulation and I know it's possible to solve this question using `data.table`

Comment: @Rafael Ok, just fyi, tags should not be used to get attention and should reflect the original poster's intentions, not what's used in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data.frame always has alternating structure as `alt_test` and `alt_ref`, then you can manually construct the subset index as below:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(myDf)
myDf[Reduce(function(x,y) ifelse(!is.na(x), x, ifelse(!is.na(y), y, F)),
     shift(p.Value < 0.05, n = 0:1, type = "lead")), .(Model,w0,w1,w2)]
```

Comment: Thanks this worked! One more question though; if I wanted to also get the Null_model row, how would I so that? I've tried changing the values of n = but that doesn't seem to do the trick. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can add a `or` condition in the shift to pick the row individually. `myDf[Reduce(function(x,y) ifelse(!is.na(x), x, ifelse(!is.na(y), y, F)),
     shift(p.Value < 0.05 | Model == "Null_model", n = 0:1, type = "lead")), .(Model,w0,w1,w2)]`

Comment: I meant that if p.value <0.05 I would like it to return the Null_model, alt_ref & alt_test rows. So I tried `myDf[Reduce(function(x,y) ifelse(!is.na(x), x, ifelse(!is.na(y), y, F)), shift(p.Value < 0.05, **n = 0:2**, type = "lead")), .(Model,w0,w1,w2)]` but that doesn't return all 3 rows.

Comment: Can you paste more of your data frame? If the solution doesn't work, I am probably missing something. BTW, you have only one data frame that contains multiple models and you want to pick the null model and models that have p.Vaue < 0.05, am I understanding correctly?

Comment: The p.value is comparing the likelihood between the Null_model and the alt_xx Model. So when p.value < 0.05 the alt_xx model fits better and I would like get the rows for alt_xx and Null model (these rows have the model estimations). I've added some rows to the data frame to show an example where the p.value is not <0.05 so I would not want the rows in this case.

Comment: Try this. `myDf[Reduce(function(x,y) ifelse(!is.na(x), x, ifelse(!is.na(y), y, NA)), shift(p.Value < 0.05, n = 0:2, type = "lead")), .(Model,w0,w1,w2)]`

Comment: Perfect, that did it! Thank you.